# Can I have same Class Root with both List and single definition of sub class?

Tags: c#, json, class, json.net

I am working on a back end data integration between an ERP system and Shopify using their rest API. Recently I came across what I see as an inconsistency and I'm not certain how to handle this in C sharp without too much duplication. Specifically this relates to their admin API and the product API.

What I did is I took the Jason response from an API that invokes a return of a list of products and I got this class structure (I'm going to keep it simple by showing only the root and the main products property)

```
public class Root
{
    public List<Product> products { get; set; }
}
```

However there is another API that allows you to get a single product an its return response does not utilize a list but a single subclass that is the same as the product subclass.

```
public class Root
{
    public Product product { get; set; }
}
```

Everything else about the overall product class is the same.  The only difference is that in one return we have a list of subclass product in the other a single element.  Without having to create two completely different classes is there a way to do this so the rest of the subclass definitions which includes other properties and subclasses can be used.  This is the subclass product:

```
public class Product
{
    public Int64 id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string body_html { get; set; }
    public string vendor { get; set; }
    public string product_type { get; set; }
    public DateTime? created_at { get; set; }
    public string handle { get; set; }
    public DateTime? updated_at { get; set; }
    public DateTime? published_at { get; set; }
    public object template_suffix { get; set; }
    public string published_scope { get; set; }
    public string tags { get; set; }
    public string admin_graphql_api_id { get; set; }
    public List<Variant> variants { get; set; }
    public List<Option> options { get; set; }
    public List<Image> images { get; set; }
    public Image image { get; set; }
}
```

I looked at inheritance but that didn't seem to quite fit and I wasn't certain if even extends would work and while my work around is too not use the get single product API but get a list of 1, I'm curious if there's a way to do this where I can not have to create two full classes just because in the root one is a list and one is a single object.

I am using Newton json to do the serialization and deserialization of the object data.

Comment: Can you show us the JSON that make you believe you need to do this?  You can have two classes with the same name in different namespaces

Comment: Use the `SingleOrArrayConverter<T>` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18997172/10263) to the linked duplicate question.  `T` would be `Product` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can have two classes with different names. When you deserialize the json, it will not matter what the root class is called.

```
public class Multi
{
    public List<Product> products { get; set; }
}

public class One
{
    public Product product { get; set; }
}
```

Or, you could have a single root class with both the list property and the single instance property. When the deserialization is done, just access the appropriate property.

```
public class Root
{
    public List<Product> products { get; set; }
    public Product product { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use inheritance:

```
public abstract class Root
{
    //All the other properties you don't want to duplicate
}

public class RootWithProduct : Root
{
    public Product product { get; set; }
}

public class RootWithProductList : Root
{
    public List<Product> products { get; set; }
}
```

When you need to deserialize, use:

```
RootWithProduct x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootWithProduct>(json);
Product product = x.product;
```

Or

```
RootWithProductList y = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootWithProductList>(json);
List<Product> products = y.products;
```